# parallel processing slower for cropping and masking rasterstack

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, raster

I am working on a problem where I need to crop and mask a rasterstack to a series of shapefiles. Here is a reproducible example:

```
# Example data ------------------------------------------------------------

#create example raster stack
r1 = raster(nrows=1000,ncol=1000,xmn=60,xmx=90,ymn=0,ymx=25)
rr = lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1))))
rrstack=stack()
for (i in 1:length(rr)){
  stacknext=rr[[i]]
  rrstack=stack(rrstack,stacknext)
}


#create example shapefile list

lats=runif(10,min=0,max=25)
lons=runif(10,min=60,max=90)
exnames=paste0("city_",letters[1:10])
coords=data.frame(names=exnames,lats=lats,lons=lons)
coords_sf = st_as_sf(coords,coords=c("lons","lats"),crs=4326,dim ="XY")
circle1=st_buffer(coords_sf, 1E3)
circle100=st_buffer(coords_sf,1E5)
circle500=st_buffer(coords_sf,5E5)
circlist=list(circle1=circle1,circle100=circle100,circle500=circle500)

circlist_reproj=lapply(circlist,function(x) st_transform(x,crs(rrstack[[1]])))
```

I developed a series of nested for loops to crop and mask the rasterstack to the shapefiles:

```
start <- proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]]))
dellist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
mystack <- stack()
for(k in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]])) {
  for(j in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
    for (i in 1:nlayers(rrstack)){
      maskraster <- raster::mask(rrstack[[i]],circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
      maskraster <- raster::crop(maskraster,circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
      mystack <- stack(mystack,maskraster)
    }
    dellist[[j]] <- mystack
    mystack <- stack()
  }
  citlist[[k]] <- dellist
  dellist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
}
basetime <- proc.time()-start
```

For my actual dataset, this takes days to complete. I developed a parallel process to speed up the above code

```
cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-2) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)
parstart=proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]]))
dellist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
for(k in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]])) {
  for(j in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
    parrasterstack <- foreach(i=1:nlayers(rrstack),.packages=c('raster','sf')) %dopar% {
    maskraster <- raster::mask(rrstack[[i]],circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
    raster::crop(maskraster,circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
    }
  parrasterstack <- stack(parrasterstack)
  dellist[[j]] <- parrasterstack
  parrasterstack <- NULL
  }
citlist[[k]] <- dellist
dellist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Running both methods of processing, I discovered that the sequential process is faster than the parallel process.

```
> basetime #sequential process
   user  system elapsed 
 19.858   4.124  24.283 

> partime #parallel process
   user  system elapsed 
 41.415  10.153 132.262
```

I repeated the code on a different machine with more cores and got a wider difference.
Why is the parallel process slower in all aspects, and is there a way to speed up the processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your sequential approach I get

```
proc.time()-start
#   user  system elapsed 
#  18.86    2.57   21.44
```

Cutting an unnecessary loop, and using crop *before* mask makes this go about 8x faster

```
start <- proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]]))

for(k in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]])) {
    for(j in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
        r <- crop(rrstack, circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
        citlist[[k]][[j]] <- mask(r, circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
    }
}
proc.time()-start
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.41    0.30    2.70
```

And `terra` is 3x faster than `raster`

```
library(terra)
rrstack <- rast(rrstack)
circlist_reproj <- lapply(circlist_reproj, vect)

start <- proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]]))

for(k in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[1]])) {
    for(j in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
        r <- crop(rrstack, circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
        citlist[[k]][[j]] <- mask(r, circlist_reproj[[j]][k,])
    }
}
proc.time()-start
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.70    0.19    0.89
```

So that is 24x faster.

Also, the loop should really be written like this to be safe:

```
start <- proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
for(i in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
    for(j in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[i]])) {
        r <- crop(rrstack, circlist_reproj[[i]][j,])
        citlist[[i]][[j]] <- mask(r, circlist_reproj[[i]][j,])
    }
}
proc.time()-start
```

And with terra you can do crop and mask in one step, and using that may be as much as 35x faster.

```
start <- proc.time()
citlist <- vector(mode='list',length=length(circlist_reproj))
for(i in 1:length(circlist_reproj)) { 
    for(j in 1:nrow(circlist_reproj[[i]])) {
        citlist[[i]][[j]] <- crop(rrstack, circlist_reproj[[i]][j,], mask=TRUE)
    }
}
proc.time()-start
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.46    0.11    0.56
```

You can now again see if the parallelization can help if that is still necessary (it is rarely worth it for this type of problem). Perhaps do that for the outer-most loop, to keep the overhead limited. But note that while you can do that with `raster`, but you cannot do that with `terra` (that will eventually be available "under the hood").

Finally, you provide no context, but what you are doing looks odd. Do you want to use `extract` instead? You could do, for example:

```
e <- lapply(circlist_reproj, function(v) extract(rrstack, v))
```

That is not the fastest method, but perhaps the clearest code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! To address your question, my goal is to create a set of concentric circles around city centers for a rasterstack. My full dataset has 300+ rasters in a rasterstack and ~400 cities. I tried using `extract` in the beginning stages but got the following error : `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"matrix", "sf"’` and moved to the current method.

Comment: Thank you Robert, the terra approach has worked for me. I used ```crop``` and then ```mask```.